# Pretty-printing XML using Java

Tags: java, xml, saxparser, pretty-print, xerces

There are a dozen threads regarding that topic, but all of them contain answers that do not work for me in a satisfactory manner. It seems one needs to use a specific DOM implementation. However, I cannot get it to read the xml input:

```
@Test
public void testPrettyPrintConvertDomLevel3() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String unformattedXml
            = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?><QueryMessage\n"
            + "        xmlns=\"http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message\"\n"
            + "        xmlns:query=\"http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/query\">\n"
            + "    <Query>\n"
            + "        <query:CategorySchemeWhere>\n"
            + "   \t\t\t\t\t         <query:AgencyID>ECB\n\n\n\n</query:AgencyID>\n"
            + "        </query:CategorySchemeWhere>\n"
            + "    </Query>\n\n\n\n\n"
            + "</QueryMessage>";

    System.out.println(prettyPrintWithXercesDomLevel3(unformattedXml.getBytes("UTF-16")));
}
```

Here is the method:

```
public static String prettyPrintWithXercesDomLevel3(byte[] input) {
    try {
//System.setProperty(DOMImplementationRegistry.PROPERTY,"org.apache.xerces.dom.DOMImplementationSourceImpl");
        DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
        DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS) registry.getDOMImplementation("XML 3.0 LS 3.0");
        if (impl == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No DOMImplementation found !");
        }

        log.info(String.format("DOMImplementationLS: %s", impl.getClass().getName()));

        LSParser parser = impl.createLSParser(
                DOMImplementationLS.MODE_SYNCHRONOUS,
                //"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml");
        log.info(String.format("LSParser: %s", parser.getClass().getName()));
        LSInput lsi = impl.createLSInput();
        lsi.setByteStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(input));
        Document doc = parser.parse(lsi);

        LSSerializer serializer = impl.createLSSerializer();
        serializer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print",Boolean.TRUE);
        LSOutput output = impl.createLSOutput();
        output.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        output.setByteStream(baos);
        serializer.write(doc, output);
        return baos.toString();
//            return serializer.writeToString(doc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

However, the pretty-printing does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: try changing `xml.getBytes()` to `xml.getBytes("UTF-8")`

Comment: As a side note, I'd consider using [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: as a side note, it is an example only. and the string is in ASCII. If you don't know about Java's XML internals, ignore this thread please.

Comment: That's a lot of code just for pretty printing a piece of xml, have you had a look at [jdom2](http://www.jdom.org/)'s [Format#getPrettyFormat](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/Format.html#getPrettyFormat%28%29)?

Comment: Also please describe what is a *satisfactory manner* and *the pretty-printing does not work*

Comment: thx. jdom2 is just great for that purpose.

Comment: @user1050755 cool, you could post your result as answer and accept it so that the question is no longer open. Btw, if your source xml provides `utf-16` as encoding then you might want to reflect that in your output using the `f.setEncoding("UTF-16");`, the `Format` defaults to `utf-8` as you have noticed.

Answer (score 0):

```html
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

/**
 *
 * @author lananda
 */
public class PrettyXmlWriter {
    
     public static void main(String... args){
        String unformattedXml
                = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>"
                + "<QueryMessage\n"
                + "        xmlns=\"http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message\"\n"
                + "        xmlns:query=\"http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/query\">\n"
                + "    <Query>\n"
                + "        <query:CategorySchemeWhere>\n"
                + "   \t\t\t\t\t         <query:AgencyID>ECB\n\n\n\n</query:AgencyID>\n"
                + "        </query:CategorySchemeWhere>\n"
                + "    </Query>\n\n\n\n\n"
                + "</QueryMessage>";
        unformattedXml = unformattedXml.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        String format = format(unformattedXml);
        System.out.println(format);
    }

       public static String format(String xml) {
        try {
            final InputSource src = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
            final Node document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(src).getDocumentElement();
            final Boolean keepDeclaration = Boolean.valueOf(xml.startsWith("<?xml"));

        //May need this: System.setProperty(DOMImplementationRegistry.PROPERTY,"com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DOMImplementationSourceImpl");
            final DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
            final DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS) registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");
            final LSSerializer writer = impl.createLSSerializer();
            writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", Boolean.TRUE); // Set this to true if the output needs to be beautified.
            writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("xml-declaration", keepDeclaration); // Set this to true if the declaration is needed to be outputted.
            return writer.writeToString(document);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you were half right: using getBytes() assumed UTF-8/ASCII, so I used getBytes("UTF-16") and it is ok now. Source encoding is UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding of your Java source file must also match what you are trying to run with. If you are using Eclipse the default encoding is CP-1252 for some reason. The first thing I do when I put in a new version of Eclipse is change the file encoding to UTF-8.

I used your code and it worked fine since my source file encoding was UTF-8.

Comment: totally correct. however, pretty-printing still does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Update: it seems that [all whitespace is significant in XML](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/wang-whitespace-092897.html): "Based on the W3C XML specification, the Oracle XML Developer's Kit (XDK) XML parsers, by default, preserves all whitespace.". Therefore it is quite reasonable *NOT* to make that feature part of a public API. org.jdom2 provides a reasonable implementation:

```
@Test
public void testPrettyPrintConvertDomLevel3() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, JDOMException, IOException {
    String unformattedXml
            = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?><QueryMessage\n"
            + "        xmlns=\"http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message\"\n"
            + "        xmlns:query=\"http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/query\">\n"
            + "    <Query>\n"
            + "        <query:CategorySchemeWhere>\n"
            + "   \t\t\t\t\t         <query:AgencyID>ECB \n </query:AgencyID>\n"
            + "        </query:CategorySchemeWhere>\n"
            + "    </Query>\n\n\n\n\n"
            + "</QueryMessage>";
    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.build(new ByteArrayInputStream(unformattedXml.getBytes("UTF-16")));
    Format f = Format.getPrettyFormat();
    f.setLineSeparator(LineSeparator.NL);
    f.setTextMode(Format.TextMode.TRIM_FULL_WHITE);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    new XMLOutputter(f).output(doc, baos);
    assertEquals("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
            + "<QueryMessage xmlns=\"http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message\" xmlns:query=\"http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/query\">\n"
            + "  <Query>\n"
            + "    <query:CategorySchemeWhere>\n"
            + "      <query:AgencyID>ECB \n"
            + " </query:AgencyID>\n"
            + "    </query:CategorySchemeWhere>\n"
            + "  </Query>\n"
            + "</QueryMessage>\n", baos.toString());
}
```